# Predator-prey simulation using Python. Problems with Python reading equation wrong?

Tags: python

I'm doing a predator prey simulation that prints the number of prey and predators in a certain period.

This is my first time posting so if there are any problems please let me know.

The information I am implementing for testing is:

```
a= .1
b= .01
c= .01
d= .00002
prey_population = 1000
predator_population = 20
periods = 10

a = float(input("Enter the rate at which prey birth exceeds natural death: "))
b = float(input("Enter the rate of predation: "))
c = float(input("Enter the rate at which predator deaths exceed births without food: "))
d = float(input("Predator increase with the presence of food: "))

prey_population = int(input("Enter prey population: "))
predator_population = int(input("Enter predator population: "))

periods = int(input("Enter the number of periods: "))

for i in range(1, periods + 1):
    prey_population = int(prey_population * (1 + a - b * predator_population))
    predator_population = int(predator_population * (1 - c + d * prey_population))

    print("After period", i, "there are", predator_population, "predators")
    print("After period", i, "there are", prey_population, "prey")
```

My information is accurate for prey until the 6th period, my predator output is accurate only to the 3rd period.

My output is:

```
After period 1 there are 20 predators
After period 1 there are 900 prey

After period 2 there are 20 predators
After period 2 there are 810 prey

After period 3 there are 20 predators
After period 3 there are 729 prey

After period 4 there are 20 predators
After period 4 there are 656 prey

After period 5 there are 20 predators
After period 5 there are 590 prey

After period 6 there are 20 predators
After period 6 there are 531 prey

After period 7 there are 19 predators
After period 7 there are 477 prey

After period 8 there are 18 predators
After period 8 there are 434 prey

After period 9 there are 17 predators
After period 9 there are 399 prey

After period 10 there are 16 predators
After period 10 there are 371 prey
```

The numbers it should show are:

```
After period 1 there are 20 predators
After period 1 there are 900 prey

After period 2 there are 20 predators
After period 2 there are 808 prey

After period 3 there are 20 predators
After period 3 there are 724 prey

After period 4 there are 21 predators
After period 4 there are 648 prey

After period 5 there are 21 predators
After period 5 there are 580 prey

After period 6 there are 21 predators
After period 6 there are 518 prey

After period 7 there are 21 predators
After period 7 there are 463 prey

After period 8 there are 21 predators
After period 8 there are 413 prey

After period 9 there are 21 predators
After period 9 there are 369 prey

After period 10 there are 21 predators
After period 10 there are 330 prey
```

Comment: I'm not sure how you are intending to use all your numbers, but my guess off the top of my head is either a rounding problem or an order of operations problem in your (1 + a - b * predator_population) and such.

Comment: Clean up your code, any possibly someone will be so nice to check your algorithm. But you cannot really expect to get help on this here. What do *you* think is wrong? The difference between expected output and actual output increases with the number of iterations, so you are doing a mistake in your algorithm.

Comment: When you update the value of `predator_population`, do you intend for it to use the new value of `prey_population` instead of the old value?  Because that's what's happening.

Comment: Apologies, I'm almost positive it is a problem with the order of operations. or something in the algorithm. Yes I intend to use the new value of the prey_population and predator_population. Basically as the prey get "eaten" the predators number should grow, at a rate of .00002 with the presence of food. It should be going up but in mine it is going down. Even keeping the numbers as a float the predator output is going down. I can keep fiddling with the equation, I know there's a problem in there somewhere, most likely with the parenthesis.

Comment: FYI: It is not just a simple matter of rounding each period vs not rounding each perion. Without rounding the actual numbers (and just rounding for display) the expected numbers after period 10 are 20 predators, 335 prey.

Comment: If you print all your variables at each step, you can figure out exactly where it's doing something other than what you want, and exactly which calculation (on which line) is generating the first unexpected result. That would be the place to start if you were trying to solve this yourself.

Comment: (Also, if breaking down operations step-by-step led you to a place where you knew the line that was getting the wrong result, and the variables **at that step of the algorithm**, you could ask a focused question only about that one line, rather than something that requires a whole mess of code and has the potential -- if not the likelihood -- to incorporate more than one problem).

Comment: @Djb14 you need some [rubber duck debugging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) of your algorithm. Use StackOverflow as your rubber duck: edit your post and explain exactly how those two last lines that update predators and prey should work. You'll notice that you didn't ask them to do what you thought you had asked them to do. We don't know what it is, but that's what rubber duck debugging is for.

Comment: Why do you expect the numbers you do? When I run the numbers by hand for the first few periods (while the predator population remains at 20), I find the results that your code is giving (each period, the prey population declines by 10%). Perhaps your expectations are wrong, not your code?

Answer (score 3):

Each turn you update the value of `prey_population` before using the new value to calculate `predator_population`. This is throwing off the results.

Comment: It's true that the OP is doing this, but are we sure fixing it will recover the "expected" results?

Comment: I was just checking that (after all it's an old, known pitfall), but this doesn't bring up the numbers OP is looking for.

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly, I should make a new variable in front of the equation to hold the new information, then bring it back to the original prey/predator_population to be used in the equation in the next turn?

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem, yes it was rounding. The int in the equation was rounding the answer. I changed it to a float and rounded in the print statement. I very much appreciate the help from everyone.

Comment: You still need to do two things to make results as expected: (1) follow @HughBothwell 's advice and use another variable to remember the current number of preys, before you update it, and use this to calculate new predators; and (2) don't just round down with int, but round up if above 0.5 (you can just add 0.5 before making it to int at the print statement).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this qualifies as an answer, but it's too long to be put in a comment, so ["practicality beats purity"](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/).

What you're asking your code to do, for every turn is:

The new number of **preys** is equal to:

- the old number of preys

  - plus this turn's new births (birth rate * current preys) **(1)**
  - minus this turn's killed preys [(predation rate * current predators) * current preys] **(1)**
  - round this all down.

The new number of **predators** is equal to:

- the old number of predators

  - minus the fixed rate of death (death rate * current predators) **(1)**
  - plus the "food births" [("food birth" rate * new number of preys) * current predators] **(1)**
  - round this all down.

Is this what it's supposed to do?

**(1)**  at this point the new number isn't rounded down yet

Comment: Yes that sounds fairly accurate if I'm understanding it correctly. I need to take the new number of prey and predators (after the first run through is 900 prey and 20 predators). Then print prey and predators, then take that new number (900 prey and 20 predators) into the equation for the 2nd time around. I've put this equation in a calculator and I've gotten the correct numbers. It is something with my equation, I will continue to try and work it out.

Comment: what I put in the calculator was

Comment: Sorry, hit enter. Here is what I did.

what I put in the calculator was 
Prey:
1000*(1+.1-.01*20) = 900

900*(1+.1-.01*20.2 = 808.2

808.2*(1+.1-.01*20.3616) = 724.4575488


This is for the predator.

20 * (1 - .01 + .00002 * 1000)  = 20.2


20.2 *(1-.01 + .00002 * 900) = 20.3616


I think the rounding in the equation might be throwing off the amount.

Comment: Yep, so you're not rounding down the number actually... i.e. in the second calculation of the preys, you used 20.2 and not 20; and you used 808.2 and not 808